# Use hex2bin() php or unhex() on mysql insert?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering what the best approach is to insert an hex value as binary into a DB.

I can do:

```
hex2bin($var)
```

in php, but I can also do

```
INTO column = UNHEX('varstring')
```

in MySQL.

Performance wise what would be best ? and overall what would be best to do?

Comment: If anything can  be done by mysql , we should go for it.

Comment: What is the problem with the value of $var that you can't just save it in the database? What is the content of `$var`? And what do you want to save in the database? Also, what is the data type of the column you want to save the data in?

Comment: Performance wise: try both and benchmark what is fastest in your situation. I don't think it will make much difference, unless you are working with a really large string. And there are to many factors that must be taken into account to give a single answer of what is fastest (for example external SQL-server vs localhost). Overall: Normally I would agree with the comment of @user2486, but more on calculations (like SQL `SUM()` vs PHP `array_sum()`) than on data conversion - you wouldn't do `htmlspecialchars` in SQL either. In this case: I don't think it really matters (assuming col type BLOB).

Comment: @Progman it's will be a uuid as HEX I need to store as Binary. It's very bad in performance on PK's to have $var as string in a DB.

Comment: @YamaKasi Don't use UUID as a primary key for your tables, this would result in a lot of page movings on the hard drive when you insert new UUIDs which are between existing rows. Use a normal AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY integer column like everyone else for PKs.

Comment: @Progman there a lot of (optimized) prove of concepts (by Percona as well) that it's no problem to use a UUID, it's made for it. AI is very bad "business wise".

Comment: @Progman "Like everyone else" yeah, for their school assignments